# What is Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Javascript - an object-oriented computer programming language commonly used to create interactive effects within web browsers.

interactive - allowing a two-way flow of information between a computer and a computer-user; responding to a user's input.

I'm confused if the computer (inside interactive's definition) that it is meant to is the server-side? or just something else?

and also ... what does "responding to a user's input" means? and how/why is it important?

Comment: JavaScript is downloaded and executed locally by the browser's JavaScript engine.

Comment: All programming code is based on the concept of input data and output data.  A user will provide user interaction ( user input ) and JavaScript will output what it was coded to output ( in other words perform a response to that input ).  If you are unfamilar with the word "respond", I strongly suggest, you look the word up in a dictionary.

Comment: Your definition is very restrictive, and in my mind wrong.  Javascript is not limited to "create interactive effects within web browsers."  Today Javascript is a popular programming language used in a variety of applications.  Its a programming language, just like Java, C# or PHP is a programming language.

Comment: if I put some data, for example I put my name "Jubiluk" and then how will Javascript respond to it? What would it do to my name?

Comment: It would do whatever the programmer had programmed it to do.

Comment: @jubilukbabawakis - We cannot tell you what will happen because you cannot and did not provide us with JavaScript your asking about.  I am not saying you should do that, because that question, will be closed for not being on topic here.  Just saying it can do anything you want it to do provided you write the code to do that anything.

Comment: @jubilukbabawakis: You've had all 3 questions posted so far across [two](http://superuser.com/users/449563/jubiluk-babawakis) [accounts](http://superuser.com/users/449947/jubiluk-babawakis) downvoted and closed. I suggest you pick up some basic programming tutorials or you'll end up getting question-banned here.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm confused if the computer (inside interactive's definition) that it is meant to is the server-side? or just something else?

It just means the computer that the user is interacting with.

> and also ... what does "responding to a user's input" means? and how/why is it important?

That's the difference between things that are interactive and things that you just observe -- interactive things respond to your input.

Also, I would add that about the only thing you can learn from a definition of "Javascript" is that it's the proper name of a particular programming language. It's not a class of things like "computer" or "car", it's one particular thing.

A definition is only meant to provide sufficient information to identify a particular thing. For example, I could define "jubiluk babawakis" as "a user of the superuser site who asked a question about Javascript" but that doesn't tell me very much about you.